# Proper way to add property to every object inside an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm iterating an object that has many objects of the same type inside it. On each object I need to add a property running through the entire object. I manage to do this with `reduce` but this is pretty ugly to read and I believe must have something more readable to do.

I need to keep the object keys, but just add a prop on each.

```js
const myObj = {
  key1: { /* data */ },
  key2: { /* data */ },
  key3: { /* data */ }
}

Object.keys(myObj).reduce((acc, value) => ({
  ...acc,
  [value]: {
    ...myObj[value],
    newProperty: 'foo',
  },
}), {});
```

I believed that lodash must have something that make this better, but I fail to find something that does the trick even on lodash or using the array/object API.

Comment: Are you trying to avoid mutation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map to an array of entries instead, then use `Object.fromEntries`:

```js
const myObj = {
  key1: { /* data */ },
  key2: { /* data */ },
  key3: { /* data */ }
};
const output = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(myObj).map(
    ([key, obj]) => [key, { ...obj, newProperty: 'foo' }]
  )
);
console.log(output);
```

If mutation is acceptable, it's easier:

```js
const myObj = {
  key1: { /* data */ },
  key2: { /* data */ },
  key3: { /* data */ }
};
for (const obj of Object.values(myObj)) {
  obj.newProperty = 'foo';
}
console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are all new to the idea of **values or entries** you can do it this way

```
const myObj = {
  key1: { "hi": 1 },
  key2: { "hi": 1 },
  key3: { "hi": 1  }
}

for(let property in myObj){
  myObj[property]["newProperty"] = "foo"
}

console.log(myObj)
```